# How to enable innodb engine in Zend Server CE

Tags: mysql

I installed Zend Server CE 5.1.0 on Mac OS X. I need to enable innodb storage engine, but I cannot find the my.cnf file and I cannot find any options to do it through the web interface. 
What's the best practice to do it? I cannot find anything on google or using the zend server documentation...

Comment: belongs on http://serverfault.com/ Q&A for system administrators and desktop support professionals

Answer (score 0):

From: http://akrabat.com/php/some-notes-on-zend-server-ce-for-mac-os-x/

> The only other gotcha I noticed is that my.cnf is in
>   /usr/local/zend/mysql/data whereas I would have thought that
>   /usr/local/zend/etc would have been more logical.

Comment: Thank you very much. But the data directory is read/write protected by default, and I think that it's not a best practice edit a file inside it... Maybe innodb are not supported in Zend Server and this is an "hack" to enable it, but I prefer a supported solution if exists

Comment: That would be strange indeed. As far as I know, MySQL shipped with Zend Server is just regular MySQL Community edition (which not only supports InnoDB, but has it set to be a default engine). Anyway here: http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-Community-Edition/zend-server-community-edition.htm they say you can edit `my.cnf` file to set up a root password, so editing it to enable InnoDB should be no problem too.